# Strange blocks behaviour, transactions are dropped from a validated block

Tags: web3js, transactions, infura, blocks, goerli

I have faced a very strange issue on **Goerli Testnet** using infura. The number of transactions in a blocks dropped from **168** transactions to **164**.

I'm working on a blocks tracker, after receiving the block (**newBlocksHeader subscription**) i traverse the blocks transactions received from (`web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber, true)`) and filter out the required.

One of the transaction went missing. So when i tried to fetch the block again i saw the number of transactions are different from the one that i previously logged.

This is what my system logged Block **4988374** has **168** txs and filtered are 18.

[image: Image 1]

This is what i got when i try to debug by missing transaction, Block **4988374** has **164** txs and filtered are 23. This time my missing transaction was included in this block.

[image: image 2]

I'm not sure what is happening here, how i can build a reliable system that doesn't miss any transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Minor blockchain reorganisations up to 6 blocks deep are normal for Ethereum. Ethereum mainnet with proof of work has only probabilistic finality, not true finality and any block is subject to disappearing.

[More about finality here](https://vitalik.ca/general/2021/06/18/verkle.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue only on infura api. So i switched to my own RPC node and now i haven't seen this issue again.